# Trigger angular element event from regular JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, android-webview

I'm trying to auto populate a page which is written using Angular which I load into a webview in my app.

There is an element in the page which has the following syntax:

```html
<input id="element" ng-model="model" ng-blur="onInput('input')">
```

Now, I'm populating the data from my app into the field by injecting JS.

```js
document.getElementById("element").value = "myvalue"
```

However, the ng-blur event isn't firing. If I manually type the data in the field it fires. How to fire the ng-blur event?

I've tried calling the regular `onblur` handler on the element, but it is `null`. Also tried doing an eval like this:

```js
let elem = document.getElementById("element")
eval(elem.attributes["ng-blur"])
```

But this also failed because the scope is wrong. How to fire angular events from regular JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Blur is fired when the element has lost the focus, so when you click outside.
Changing the value of the input won't fire this event.

Here you could use ngModelChange just like that :

```
<input id="element" [(ngModel)]="model" (ngModelChange)="onInput($event)">
```

ngModelChange is quite explicite, it's fired when the ngModel value as changed

Moreover i'm not sure that using ngModel without brackets and parentheses works, but maybe it's a syntax i don't know.

Last thing: in angular, you get the elements with 'ViewChild'

Just put a reference on the element like that :

```
<input id="element" #someInput [(ngModel)]="model" (ngModelChange)="onInput($event)">
```

Then in your typescript you need to import ViewChild

```
import {Component,ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
```

And use it like that :

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
   @ViewChild('someInput') someInput: Any;
   ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.someInput.value = 'Hey';
   }
 }
```

Comment: I don't have access to the source code of the page. I'm trying to automate an already available page. What I want is to simulate the event without user intervention.

Comment: Oh ok i was totally wrong then. 
Maybe this could helps you ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/blur

Comment: Tried it man, still no luck. Seems Angular is fetching events from some other way. Thanks though.

Comment: I'm not sure why exactly, but `element.dispatchEvent(new Event("blur"))` worked.

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati did you manage to do this?

Comment: @edmz Yes, using `element.dispatchEvent(new Event("blur"))` has worked for me.